# Download excel file using webapi and angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, excel, asp.net-web-api, closedxml

I'm trying to download a closedXml excel file in a webapi/angularjs application.

I'm returning the data from the webapi controller on the server using:

```
 HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();
 result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
 MemoryStream stream = GetStream(workbook);
 result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
 result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
 {
     FileName = "Download.xlsx"
 };
 return result;
```

and then saving it on the client using:

```
$scope.openExcel =  function (data, status, headers, deferred) {
        var type = headers('Content-Type');
        var disposition = headers('Content-Disposition');
        if (disposition) {
            var match = disposition.match(/.*filename=\"?([^;\"]+)\"?.*/);
            if (match[1])
                defaultFileName = match[1];
        }
        defaultFileName = defaultFileName.replace(/[<>:"\/\\|?*]+/g, '_');
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });

        saveAs(blob, defaultFileName);
```

Excel says the file is in a different format than specified by the extension and then doesn't open properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On projects I work on, I make a Controller for files(not an ApiController)

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public FileResult GetFile(/*params*/)
    {
        // get fileBytes
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        return base.File(fileBytes, contentType, "Download.xlsx");
    }
}
```

and then from angular, I open the file like this

```
$window.open("/Files/GetFile/" /*+ params*/);
```